# A sidebar that scrolls slower than the main content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is this impossible? I am using CSS and HTML, I have a sidebar and I have found ways to make it stick (not scroll at all) but none of the parallax examples I can find work.

I really want to avoid using JS.

```
<html container>
  <content>
    <left column>
      This content is very very long and goes for a long way down.
    </left column>
    <right column>
      This is the sidebar and is much shorter, so I want it to scroll slower than the main content.
    </right column>
  </content>
</html>
```

Is this even possible without javascript?

Comment: Here is a tutorial for a pure css version of parallax: https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS3 perspective this is indeed possible. In fact, as the parallax is handled by the browser, it will likely behave more smoothly than if you used JavaScript. The downside is that older browsers will not support it.

CSS3 perspective involves transforming the elements along the Z axis. Elements further away will scroll more slowly. Thus you would not transform your main content along the Z-axis, so that it scrolls at its default speed, and you would transform the sidebar down the Z-axis - away from the user so to speak - so that it would scroll slower.

As you transform into the Z-axis the sidebar will become smaller (or larger if you move up the axis) as it is further away from the user. You will need to calculate the correct scale for its distance and apply that, making it appear at its original size.

I can't guarantee that this code will work with your current implementation as you haven't provided your CSS. But it would typically work something like this:

```
content {
    ...
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
column {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
left {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
right {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

Using the perspective and translateZ values, the scale factor to appear at its original size is 1 + (translateZ * -1) / perspective.

A codepen that demonstrates this with a long content section and shorter, slower scrolling sidebar is found at https://codepen.io/jla-/pen/NOGxpQ.

[This article](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) has more information on implementing a parallax effect in CSS.

Comment: Wow, this is a perfect answer. Thank you!